# Is happens-before relation given in case of invokeLater() or invokeAndWait?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, invokelater, happens-before

Pretty sure it is this way - but I like to know for sure - 
is happens-before relation given in case of invokeLater() or invokeAndWait()?

The methods are defined in (SwingUtilities respectively) AWT.EventQueue.
I guess there is synchronization involved when something is entered in the EventQueue
and hence as result of the synchronization, the happens-before relation and finally the visibility is given.

But is it really that way?
(and where can I find that information?)

---

e.g.
inside some worker thread

```
    ...
    *<1> heavy computation modifying lots of DATA*
    ...
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                *<2> is visibility of modified DATA guaranteed?*
            }
        }
    );
```

---

e.g.
inside some thread

```
    ...
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                *<1> change some DATA*
            }
        }
    );
    *<2> is visibility of modified DATA guaranteed?*
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: In the first example in some thread at position <1> data is changed and then invokeLater() is called. Is the changed data visible at position <2> inside the runnable.

Comment: invokeAndWait must be called out of EDT, tested by isEventDispatchThread must to returns false, otherwise a few exception can freeze Swing GUI, can be forever depends of

Comment: n the first example in some thread at position <1> data is changed and then invokeLater() is called. Is the changed data visible at position <2> inside the runnable.
In the second example again at position <1> data is changed and later (outside of the runnable) when invokeAndWait() has finished it is accessed at position <2>. Is the changed data visible again?

Comment: Thanks to "mKorbel" for the response.
Looking at "JAVA - Concurrency in practice" from Brain Goetz at all
you need the synchronize to guarantee the happens-before relation and as result of that you gain visibility of data.
I can't find any information that invokeLater() guarantees happens-before or visibility of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: yes, there is a *happens-before* relationship imposed between actions of the thread calling `invokeLater`/`invokeAndWait` and actions on the EDT of the runnable thereby submitted. Without that the sanity of the whole API would be at stake.

Unfortunately, it is hard to come by any *authoritative* source which would confirm that. That happens with a lot of stuff regarding Swing and concurrency.

For a bit more information, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20908679/1103872) by *trashgod*, a long-time Swing guru.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks! I guess, I have to accept that.
Since the AWT EventQueue guarantees FIFO order when tasks/Runnables are pushed into the EventQueue by invokeLater(), there has to be synchronization. As a result of this we can assume that the “call of invokeLater()” happens-before the “start of the task” and visibility is given (in this direction). The task sees at least the values at the time when invokeLater() was called.
Anyway, I would have preferred not to be required to consider about internal implementations, but to have an authoritative source (e.g. API) guaranteeing me that.

Comment: I think that this behavior does not necessarily have to be documented. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64497416/3882565.

Comment: In my opinion it is a mind-boggling oversight that the documentation fails to explicitly state that the invoke... methods establish a happens-before relationship. Exchanging the data between EDT and other threads is far from being an edge case scenario