# Is JMapViewer thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, jmapviewer

I'm writing an applicaton that uses JMapViewer. There are several threads (executed in a ThreadPoolExecutor) which acts over the displayed map (mainly creating/destroying and changing the color of some MapMarkerCircle). Does this violate the Single Thread Rule? Should I run the code which acts over the map in the done() method of a SwingWorker to make sure it will be executed in the Event Dispatch Thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the setter functions for markers and such on `JMapViewer` call `repaint()`, you will need to ensure they are only called on the event dispatch thread. [`repaint()` is documented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906034/2101267) to not be thread-safe although it may currently work correctly.

Comment: Right, "you still need to synchronize access to any data that is shared between threads."