# Does calling `repaint()` require "invoke"?

Tags: java, performance, swing, timer

Does calling `Component#repaint` require [`invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) or [`invokeAndWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait(java.lang.Runnable)) if it is not called within an AWT event dispatching thread?

I've created a minimal clock (just for practice and to extend later on), code as MCVE below:

```
package digiclock;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ClockPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public class ClockTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Repainter());
            var delay = calculateDelay(precision);
            timer.schedule(new ClockTimerTask(), delay);
        }
    }

    public class Repainter implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ClockPanel.this.repaint();
        }
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private Precision precision;

    public ClockPanel(Precision precision) {
        this.precision = precision;
        
        this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        // note that the Swing timer is so imprecise that it's usefulness is basically reduced to zero
        this.timer = new Timer("ClockTimer");
        var initialDelay = calculateDelay(precision);
        this.timer.schedule(new ClockTimerTask(), initialDelay);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        // TODO take care of resizing specific to size of time etc
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 40));
        g.drawString(getTimeString(precision, LocalTime.now()), 10, 50);
    }

    private static int calculateDelay(Precision precission) {
        Instant delayNow = Instant.now();
        return precission.getInMilli() - (int) (delayNow.toEpochMilli() % precission.getInMilli());
    }

    private static String getTimeString(Precision precision, LocalTime time) {
        // TODO take care of precision
        
        // pattern for 24 hrs
        DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        return time.format(pattern);
    }
}
```

```
package digiclock;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DigiClock extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final double MM_IN_INCH = 0.0393701;

    private static final Dimension DIMENSION_IN_MM = new Dimension(120, 40);

    private static int RES = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();

    private static Dimension convertFromDimensionInMM(Dimension dimInMM) {
        return new Dimension(mmToPixels(dimInMM.width), mmToPixels(dimInMM.height));

    }

    private static int mmToPixels(int mm) {
        return (int) (mm * MM_IN_INCH * RES);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var clock = new DigiClock();
        clock.setTitle("24-hour clock");
        clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        clock.setSize(convertFromDimensionInMM(DIMENSION_IN_MM));
        clock.add(new ClockPanel(Precision.SECOND));
        clock.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
package digiclock;

public enum Precision {
    DECISECOND(100), SECOND(1000), MINUTE(60_000);

    private int inMS;

    private Precision(int inMS) {
        this.inMS = inMS;
    }

    public int getInMilli() {
        return inMS;
    }
}
```

and I want my code to wait the minimal amount of time possible, for obvious reasons.

Comment: It is thread-safe to call `repaint()` off of the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT)

Comment: Relevant Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com java swing call repaint off of edt](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+call+repaint+off+of+edt)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, thanks, I tried to find it using `invoke` in the searches but that drew up straws. Anyway, I can simplify my clock now.

Comment: Yes, the key is often to know the right search terms

Comment: Yep, and normally I'm quite good at that, but yeah, sometimes you fail.

Comment: I think it's part and parcel of being human. Good luck

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You might want to know about [this thread too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905985/is-the-swing-repaint-method-still-safe-to-use-outside-the-edt-in-java-7)

Comment: Thank you for that information. Side question: why use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` and not `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: I've tried `javax.swing.Timer` first and it behaved terribly. Did the exact same calculation and it was often off more than 0.5s **in both directions**. It's shit, basically. This on Ubuntu, don't know if the Windows version behaves any better...

Comment: Note by the way that **both** the links in the accepted answer that you pointed to don't work anymore, so now I'm also left without any indication that it **should** work; I've reinstituted the `invokeLater` in for now - correct behavior before performance...

Comment: It's never been fully reliable, for length of time slices, but neither is `java.util.Timer`, which is why all delta times should be based on direct calculations, and slices made small enough to allow for fine grain measurements

Comment: True, but I hope that the Java timer is at least not early, and I get the current time in `repaint` anyway. If it messes up after all that I'll just wait till the next second...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By the way, the Java timer has ~1 ms accuracy on my system - and it is never early :)

Comment: Fair enough. Do you wish me to re-open your question?

Comment: No, and I've left a comment below the accepted answer to the thread I pointed out. I just thought this information was useful to you as well.

Comment: And it was. Much appreciated!